# C# SQL Internal connection fatal error

Tags: c#, sql

I am getting an error when trying to connect to SQL Database through C#:

```
SqlConnection sqlc = new SqlConnection("Server=sql09.freemysql.net,3306;Database=rekklamirajmee;Uid=trubilord;Pwd=******;");
sqlc.Open()
```

When connecting through HeidiSQL, everything works, with the following settings:

[image]

Advanced on default.

I've been trying to fix it, have been Google-ing for over an hour but I cannot seem to fix it ;

Comment: And ... what is the error?

Comment: You are using a library for SQL Server (microsoft) to connect to a MySQL database. Try using the library provided by mysql: http://www.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/

Answer (score 6):

Unless I've lost my mind, the issue is that you're using the `SqlConnection` and you should be using the [`MySqlConnection`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/es/connector-net-examples-mysqlconnection.html). You can get that library from http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/. It's a completely different assembly that you need to include in your project.

`SqlConnection` connects to a Microsoft SQL Server.

Comment: That or, `OdbcConnection` from `System.Data.ODBC`?

Comment: @SeeSharp, of course you could use `Odbc`, and take a ***massive*** performance hit. You could use `Odbc` to connect to a Microsoft SQL Server, but when using the .NET framework it's not a good idea.