# Can't connect to MySQL Database with C#; Error state: 18

Tags: c#, mysql, database, connection

Below is the code I used to try to connect to a remote MySQL server. I've connected to this server with a Python script using pymysql but I am unable to connect to it with Visual Studios. The application is "fully trusted" in visual studios. When I run this, I get System.InvalidOperationException stating an internal connection fatal error.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace Rextester
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Your code goes here
            Console.WriteLine("Hello, world!!");
            SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection("User ID={UserID};" +
                                       "password={Password};Data Source=sql9.freesqldatabase.com, 3306;" +
                                       "Trusted_Connection=yes;" +
                                       "Initial Catalog=sql9159612; " +
                                       "connection timeout=30");
            try
            {
                myConnection.Open();
                Console.WriteLine("Opened connection");
            }
            catch(Exception e) 
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Can't open connection");
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# SQL Internal connection fatal error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15643022/c-sharp-sql-internal-connection-fatal-error)

Comment: Never provide sensitive information.

Answer (score 0):

First, you'll want to download the MySql.Data package from Nuget.

Then take out ",3306" from the Data Source, and also remove the Trusted_Connection element...

```
var myConnection = new MySqlConnection("User ID={UserId};" +
                                                   "password={Password};Data Source=sql9.freesqldatabase.com;" +
                                                   "Initial Catalog={database}; " +
                                                   "connection timeout=30");
```

(I remove some of the sensitive information, fyi...)