# "Internal connection fatal error. Error state: 18" C#-SQL Ip connection error. Whole error message

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have this initial function to connect to my database

```
                public static SqlConnection cnSqlConex;
    public static bool cnOk = false;
    public static void Iniciar_Conexion_BBDD(string Address, string Port, string Database, string User, string Psswd)
    {
        cnSqlConex = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source= " + Address + " , " + Port + "; Network Library= DBMSSOCN; Initial Catalog= " + Database + "; User ID= " + User + "; Password = " + Psswd);
        try
        {
            cnSqlConex.Open();
            cnOk = true;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error al conectar a la base de datos " + e);
        }
    }
```

---

And this in the form. Using the right credentials that I'm using in MySql Workbench, in other PC.

```
        private string Address = "****";
    private string Port = "3306";
    private string Database = "****";
    private string User = "root";
    private string Psswd = "root";

    private void btnAceptar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        Funciones.Iniciar_Conexion_BBDD(Address, Port, Database, User, Psswd);
        if (Funciones.cnOk == true)
        {

            fPanel Ventana = new fPanel();
            this.Hide();
            Ventana.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
            Ventana.ShowDialog();
            this.Close();
        }
        else if (txtPsswd.Text == "Psswd" && txtUser.Text == "User")
        {

            fPanel Ventana = new fPanel();
            this.Hide();
            Ventana.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
            Ventana.ShowDialog();
            this.Close();
        }

    }
```

But when I try to login with the correct credentials, there's this error that I can't figure out what's wrong. I've tried to connect remotely with other applications and the database seems to work fine.

```
Error al conectar a la base de datos System.InvalidOperationException: Error irrecuperable de conexión interna. Estado de error: 18

   en System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.TryProcessHeader()

   en System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ConsumePreLoginHandshake(SqlAuthenticationMethod authType, Boolean encrypt, Boolean trustServerCert, Boolean integratedSecurity, Boolean& marsCapable, Boolean& fedAuthRequired)

   en System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Connect(ServerInfo serverInfo, SqlInternalConnectionTds connHandler, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64 timerExpire, Boolean encrypt, Boolean trustServerCert, Boolean integratedSecurity, Boolean withFailover, Boolean isFirstTransparentAttempt, SqlAuthenticationMethod authType, Boolean disableTnir, SqlAuthenticationProviderManager sqlAuthProviderManager)

   en System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, Boolean withFailover, Boolean isFirstTransparentAttempt, Boolean disableTnir)

   en System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, TimeoutTimer timeout)

   en System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)

   en System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling, SqlAuthenticationProviderManager sqlAuthProviderManager)

   en System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)

   en System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)

   en System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)

   en System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)

   en System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)

   en System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)

   en System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)

   en System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)

   en System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)

   en System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)

   en System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)

   en System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()

   en Manejador_Datos_TFG.Funciones.Iniciar_Conexion_BBDD(String Address, String Port, String Database, String User, String Psswd) en C:\Users\Edu-PC\Desktop\Visual Basic Studio\Manejador Datos TFG_\Manejador Datos TFG\Funciones.cs:línea 22
---------------------------
Aceptar   
---------------------------
```

I'm in a little hurry atm, excuse me for the format or for some errors. I'm new in this forum, and made this post because I can't find any answer. Thanks for reading anyway

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15643022/c-sharp-sql-internal-connection-fatal-error

Comment: For starters, *don't* hard-code the network library. Don't specify the port unless you've use a non-default port.

Comment: Can you connect to SQL Server with SSMS in the first place? Is the server running? Why are you specifying the port in the connection string, did you encounter any problems with the default?

Comment: Yes, the server is working correctly. The port can be modified because the application in going to be using different databases with different ports configured.  The server is not using the default. If I try with it, it even can't find it.

Comment: @EduFreeman that doesn't tell us anything. You still haven't explained how you connected or why you pass a port to the connection string, or why you hard-coded the library. Passing the *wrong* port guarantees the connection will fail. Did you use a custom port when connecting from other applications?